# ImportError: cannot import name 'ForkContext' from 'multiprocessing.context'

Tags: python, multiprocessing, importerror

I am trying to run a repo that I got from github. It shows the error below.
I removed multiprocessing folder from "C:\Users\yenia\anaconda3\envs\matformer\Lib" but it still occours.
Anyone has an idea how to fix it ?
If necessary, I can give more information. Thanks for your interest.

```
(.venv) C:\Users\yenia\PycharmProjects\Matformer-main\matformer\scripts\mp>python train_mp.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\yenia\PycharmProjects\Matformer-main\matformer\scripts\mp\train_mp.py", line 1, in <module>
    from matformer.train_props import train_prop_model 
  File "c:\users\yenia\pycharmprojects\matformer-main\matformer\train_props.py", line 7, in <module>
    from matformer.train import train_dgl
  File "c:\users\yenia\pycharmprojects\matformer-main\matformer\train.py", line 39, in <module>
    from matformer.data import get_train_val_loaders
  File "c:\users\yenia\pycharmprojects\matformer-main\matformer\data.py", line 15, in <module>
    from matformer.graphs import PygGraph, PygStructureDataset
  File "c:\users\yenia\pycharmprojects\matformer-main\matformer\graphs.py", line 3, in <module>
    from multiprocessing.context import ForkContext
ImportError: cannot import name 'ForkContext' from 'multiprocessing.context' (C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\multiprocessing\context.py)
```

I imported all of library that needed in repo as mentioned as;
conda create --name matformer python=3.10
conda activate matformer
conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio pytorch-cuda=11.6 -c pytorch -c nvidia
conda install pyg -c pyg
pip install jarvis-tools==2022.9.16
python setup.py

cd matformer/scripts/mp
python train_mp.py

Answer (score 0):

The `ForkContext` is only available on Unix-like systems, whereas `SpawnContext` can be used in Windows environments.

- spawn: Creates a new instance of the Python interpreter as a process. Available on Windows, Unix and MacOS.
- fork: Creates a fork of an existing Python interpreter process. Available on Unix.

Please refer to this. [Python MultiProcessing Context](https://superfastpython.com/processpoolexecutor-multiprocessing-context/)